# Password reset with Javascript and Django Rest Framework

Tags: javascript, django, rest, email, passwords

I'm trying to use the Django Rest Framework library to reset the user's password. I followed some tutorials, mainly this one: https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/. However, none of the tutorials showed how to make the password reset independent of the frontend-to-backend address.

The process described in all the tutorials I found follows a similar procedure. The user submits their email via the frontend to the backend, and then the backend sends an email to the user containing a link for password recovery. The problem, in my case, lies here. The backend needs to know the frontend's address, meaning the frontend's address needs to be hard-coded in the backend so that the link sent in the email directs to a page on the frontend.

My question is: Is there any way for the backend to discover the frontend's address during the password recovery process? Alternatively, is there an easier way to implement password recovery?